# Busybox init, Kivy python application appears to block execution of ifup

Tags: python, ethernet, sysvinit, busybox-init

I am experimenting with Buildroot, trying to create a minimal system to optimise cold boot time into a Python application (Kivy GUI). I chose to use Busybox init process because this is supposed to be optimal for embedded systems. I have a Sxx script in `/etc/init.d` that starts my app:

`#!/bin/sh
python myapp.py 2 > errlog.txt &`

This works when I pass `loglevel=8` on kernel command line. The system boots into my Kivy app and I am able to ping/ssh into the Raspberry Pi2. However if I pass `loglevel=1` then eth0 no longer comes up (everything else is ok). Numbering the startup script S99myapp so that it is executed after `S40network` does not affect the outcome. I also tried giving myapp low priority by starting it with `nice -n 19 python myapp.py 2 > errlog.txt &` but this again does not help. The problem is still there even with the simplest Kivy app possible - the 'Hello Word' example from Kivy home page.

It looks like the Kivy app is somehow preventing `ifup` from completing, unless enough time is bought with printing log messages to console. Can someone please explain what is happening? Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got to the bottom of this. Running `ifup -a -n` revealed that /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wait_iface is executed first. This is a script that delays configuration "In case we have a slow-to-appear interface (e.g. eth-over-USB)". I am using RPI2 and it has "eth-over-USB". However `wait_iface` does not execute out-of-the-box because environment vars `IF_WAIT_DELAY` and `IFACE` that it expects to find, are not set by the default Buildroot build. If I add `IFACE=eth0` and `IF_WAIT_DELAY=10` directly into `wait_iface`, eth0 comes up reliably again.

What I think was happening is not in fact that anything was 'blocking' `ifup`, rather there was a race condition - `eth0` needed to be already available when `ifup` was executed. My app delayed `eth0` availability if it ran too early. On the other hand having lots of console output delayed my app enough to ensure `eth0` was available in time.

I came across other suggestions on how to deal with this. One was to use `allow-hotplug` in `/etc/network/interfaces`. I tried it without success but I do not know if Busybox recognises this or if I did it right. Other advice was to create a `udev` rule to bring up `eth0` when it becomes available.